# How to create environment objects in SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-modelcontext

In a UIKit-based app where I'm integrating SwiftUI:

```
class SwiftDataManager {
    static let shared = SwiftDataManager()
    private init() {}

    var container: ModelContainer?

    func initializeContainer() {
        
        do {
            container = try ModelContainer(for: Cat.self, Dog.self)
            
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    ...
    //list cats and dogs
}

let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeView().environmentObject(SwiftDataManager.shared.container?.mainContext))
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Error on the `environmentObject` line:

`Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that 'ModelContext' conform to 'ObservableObject'`

How do I get the `modelContext` into `SomeView` so that I can work with the objects saved in SwiftData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how you read the model context in a SwiftUI view:

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
```

You use the overload of `@Environment` that takes an `EnvironmentValues` key path. You do not use `@EnvironmentObject` to access the model context, do you?

So in the same way, you use the `.environment` modifier that takes an `EnvironmentValues` key path to set the model context.

```
UIHostingController(rootView: Group {
    if let container = SwiftDataManager.shared.container {
        SomeView().environment(\.modelContext, container.mainContext)
    }
    // else { SomeView() } perhaps?
})
```

I'm not sure why your `container` here is optional. You should decide what to do when it is nil.